# Save text inside a table to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, local-storage

I have a table with a number of products and their price in a different column. I also have an "add to cart" button next to each product. When the button is pressed, the product and price in that row only needs to be saved to local storage. Any idea how I can do this?

This is what I have

```
body>
        
<!--     Header-->
     <div id="header"> 
      <button type="button" class="button">Basket</button>
     </div>

<!--     CSV FILE DATA WILL APPEAR HERE-->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div id="order_list" onload="appendRow()"><p id="tableintro"> Choose your desired supermarket</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>    
     
<!--THIS BUTTON WILL LOAD DATA FROM CSV FILE-->
<div id="sidebar">
         <div align="center">
 <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_tesco" class="btn btn-info">Tesco Brent Cross</button>
    </div>
     <div align="center">
         
<!--     Saving to local storage - dont work   -->
 <script>
       function SaveItem() {
       var name = document.parentNode.value;
    var data = document.parentNode.value;
    localStorage.setItem(name, data);
}
     </script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_tesco').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"Tesco.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var tesco_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<tesco_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = tesco_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {  
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<div class="12at"><td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td></div>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '<td id="lastrow"><button onclick="SaveItem()">Add</button class="addb"></td>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#order_list').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Its difficult to answer and the actual `<table>` structure with the clicked button inside table row cell is not provided.

Comment: It is shown in the <script> code at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Pass cellData as a parameter to your SaveItem function ( pass it as a string )

In the saveItem function check 
      if key 'basket' exists in localStoage then 
         append the value of selected row with a | separator 
      else 
        add a new entry

```
function SaveItem(cell_data) {
      let basket = window.localStorage.getItem('basket');
      if ( basket ) {
        basket += `|${cell_data}`;
      } else {
        basket = cell_data;
      }
      window.localStorage.setItem('basket', basket);
}

for(var count = 0; count<tesco_data.length; count++) {
        var _cellData = tesco_data[count]; 
        var cell_data = _cellData.split(",");
        table_data += '<tr>';
        for(let cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++) {  
            if(count === 0) {
                table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
            } else {
                table_data += '<div class="12at"><td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td></div>';
            }
        }
        table_data += `<td id="lastrow"><button onclick="SaveItem('${_cellData }')">Add</button class="addb"></td>`;
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#order_list').html(table_data);
```